difference between [worked at A warehouse and A manufacturing plant] vs [worked at A warehouse and A manufacturing plant]
(1) I have worked at a warehouse and a manufacturing plant before.
(2) I have worked at a warehouse and manufacturing plant before.
The first sentence has two indefinite articles and the second one has only one. Does the single article in (2) mean that the warehouse and the manufacturing plant are in the same building?

I would interpret the first sentence to refer to two different companies and jobs, one a warehouse, the other a manufacturing plant, and the second to refer to a single company and job, a company that is both a warehouse and a manufacturing plant.
But I'd also be reluctant to conclude too much based on the presence or absence of the single word "a", so if it mattered, I'd ask for clarification.

There's not much difference in any practical situation.
Structurally, the first has two coordinated noun phrases and suggests two different locations.  The second could mean a single place that functions as both.  Or it could mean exactly the same as the first, by a parallel construction (in which the repeated word "a" has been deleted)
It almost certainly doesn't matter. The speaker is telling you about their work experience, and so it matters little if the warehouse and the manufacturing plant were separate, side-by-side, or combined into a single site.
